# AngularJS and angular-translate: Using the translate filter in an object literal

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-filter, angular-translate, angular-directive

I have an angular JS app that uses angular-translate for i18n. This app also displays charts using highcharts.js. I've built a custom directive on top of highcharts-ng that lets me pass in an object literal as an expression that then gets used to configure the axes of the charts:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('xxChart', function() {
    return {
      transclude: true,
      template: '<highchart id=id config=config ng-transclude>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        id: '=',
        title: '=',
        xxXAxis: '=',
        xxYAxis: '='
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.config = {
          options: {
            chart: {
              lineWidth: 10
            },
            xAxis: $scope.xxXAxis,
            yAxis: $scope.xxYAxis,
            plotOptions: {
              spline: {
                lineWidth: 3
              },
              area: {
                lineWidth: 3
              }
            }
          },
          series: [],
          title: {
            text: $scope.title
          }
        };

        this.addSeries = function(name) {
          var series = {
            name: name,
            data: []
          };
          $scope.config.series.push(series);
          return series;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

I use the directive like this:

```
<xx-chart xx-x-axis="{title: {text: 'My x axis'}}">
...
</xx-chart>
```

Now I want to translate my app. I've noticed that this obviously won't work:

```
<xx-chart xx-x-axis="{title: {text: 'My x axis' | translate}}">
...
</xx-chart>
```

Is there a way to use the translate filter inside an object literal? If not, how should I solve my problem while sticking to the angular architecture?

Also note that I can't change the semantics of the directive in a way that breaks passing in object literals that contain other, non-translated fields.

Minimal-example-fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ssn53

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and found out the correct syntax is:

```
busy-tracker="{message:('messageId'|translate)}"
```

Note the braces enclosing the value.  In my case I don't need double curly braces enclosing the whole expression because it is interpolated by the directive (by using private scope and '&' assignment).

Answer (score 0):

Using angular interpolation should meet your requirements:

```
<xx-chart xx-x-axis="{title: {text: {{'My x axis' | translate}} }}">
...
</xx-chart>
```

Note the double curly braces {{ }}

Comment: Nope, this gives me: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ''My x axis'' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 18 of the expression [{title: {text: {{'My x axis' | translate}} }}] starting at ['My x axis' | translate}} }}].`. As far as I understand, the attribute contents is already being evaluated as an expression, but interpolation is not performed inside the object literal.

Comment: Could you publish a jsfiddle or a plunker with your code. It will be easier for me if I can play with it. Can you confirm, it is a typo         `xqXAxis: '='`,  and `xqYAxis: '='`, while in the attributes of your directive you use `xx-x-axis` and `xx-y-axis` vs `xq-x-axis and `xq-y-axis`.

Comment: Yes, this is a typo. http://jsfiddle.net/Ssn53/ is a minimal, if somewhat nonsensical example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Not really. I ended up writing a function that traverses an object hierarchy and tries to replace all strings it encounters with their translation. I then added a model watch for the directive that calls this function on every change.